# Calling a Library Function from a View (MVC C#)

Tags: c#

I have a function in my Misc library in App_Code called EncodePicture which encodes a picture.  However when I try to call the code, I get the function exists in both.  I've looked at other answer such as clearing down the temporary files, I did that but it didn't work.  The Misc Library has No namespace, does it need it?

I'm calling the function as :-

```
<img id="imgTitle" src="data:image/png;base64,@Misc.EncodePicture("/aPic/banner.jpg")" alt="" width="468" height="60" />
```

I get it Misc exists in both Universe and App_Code.....

How can I get round this problem?  The function is :-

```
using System.Security.Cryptography;


namespace Universe
{

public class Misc
{

    public static string EncodePicture(string sFilename)
    {
        string sEncode = "";

        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~" + sFilename), FileMode.Open))
        {

            System.IO.BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs);
            Byte[] bytes = br.ReadBytes((Int32)fs.Length);
            sEncode = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        }

        return sEncode;
    }
```

Please don't say hard code the value because I'm going to be using this style in other places and can't hard code all the images.  C# or VB.NET pls.

Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately.

Compiler Error Message: CS0433: The type 'Misc' exists in both 'App_Code.keoe0a1i, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' and 'Universe, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'

Comment: Can you provide the full compilation error?

Comment: Is the Misc class one that you wrote? If so, call it something more meaningful to avoid the namespace clash. Or simply call it via its fully qualified namespace path. And, yes, give it a meaningful namespace also.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Qualify via Namespace**

Depending on where your `EncodePicture()` method is defined, you can import the appropriate namespace so that it could be called within your View :

```
namespace YourProject
{
    public static class Misc
    {
        public static string EncodePicture(string file)
        {
            // Build a URL for the requested path
            return file;
        }
    }
}
```

and then simply add a `using` statement within your View :

```
@using YourProject;
```

And you should then be able to call it as expected via :

```
@Misc.EncodePicture(...)
```

Or without the using statement in a fully qualified manner :

```
@YourProject.Misc.EncodePicture(...)
```

**Reference it anywhere via the `web.config`**

If this was a method you would expect to use throughout various different Views, then you might consider adding the namespaces in your `web.config` so that it would be accessibly more easily :

```
<system.web.webPages.razor>
  <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
    <namespaces>
      <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
      <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
      <!-- Add your namespace here -->
      <add namespace="YourProject" />
    </namespaces>
  </pages>
</system.web.webPages.razor>
```

Comment: But how do I a) call the function so the output of the function is the value of a HTML Element see code at top b) why am I getting function exists in two places.

Comment: I'm assuming that your function would take the path that is passed in, read the bytes from it via `File.ReadAllBytes()` or similar and then convert it to a base-64 string (possibly through `Convert.ToBase64String()`), if you output that string from your function, then that should be alright as it's called now. With regarding the dual declarations, what is Universe? Is this another project or something that is being referenced? You might want to show what your `App_Code` code looks like as well to make this a bit easier to reproduce.

Comment: Have amended my question to include the full function.  Am puzzled why its seeing the function in two places and how the best way to call the function in the view so the encoded value is in the img tag.  As for Universe, its the namespace, the project, the project bin dll.

Comment: This could actually be the result of the function being defined in the `App_Code` folder, which may be causing it the duplicate reference (as `App_Code` contents are often compiled into the Project.DLL and an App_Code.dll as well). 

Is `App_Code` the only place that it's defined? You could try explicitly renaming your `App_Code` folder to something like `Code` or just try defining the function in an area besides `App_Code` to see if that helps.

Comment: Thanks Rion, the problem was what you said in your last comment in that I had to rename the App_Code to Code.  Never occurred to me that App_Code would be the problem.  Everything then fell into place.

Comment: Yeah, `App_Code` is one of those "special" folders that can often do things that developers don't always expect to happen.